# Mac OS X Finder scrolling stops working and locks up

Tags: osx-lion, finder

Whenever I open a browse dialog in Mac OS X Lion my finder becomes unresponsive (locks up) and scrolling stops working. I can use the mouse arrow keys to partly move around the finder and eventually after 10 - 30 seconds or so I can select things with the mouse again but it's very slow.

I think it has to do with a network drive I have setup. I think at one there was a login or wasn't a login, I don't remember but I'm guessing it's trying to connect with an old login. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Does the network drive show as a shortcut in the left panel of the Finder?

Comment: Yes. It has a section "Shared" and in that is "MyBookWorld" and "MyBookWorldBackup".

Comment: I had two entries in KeyChain for logon and deleted both and it is still locking up. Maybe a restart.

Comment: Try deleting the link to the network drive. Drag it off your "Shared" section; then see what happens. (Make sure you know how to recreate it first, of course!)

Comment: It won't let me remove it. The other folders I can drag and drop but when this is selected it doesn't do anything. I noticed in the lower left corner of the finder window a pencil with a line through it possibly to indicate "no editing".

Comment: Interesting! I restarted and it seems like it's working! (I'm guessing due to removing keychain.) Thanks for your help. If this continues to work I would say removing the keychain entry solves it.

Comment: Ah crap. I just realized I'm on my laptop. :(